# In-Memory Sqlite DB in Rails with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 application that I'm attempting to test in rspec using an in-memory sqlite database. When I run `rake` it tells me

`` You have 66 pending migrations. Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again. ``

**spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'faker'
require 'rake'

load_schema = lambda {
  load "#{Rails.root.to_s}/db/schema.rb"
}

load_schema[]

...
```

Why am I getting this error? Why do I need to run migrations when I'm simply loading the schema file? What is the correct way to test using a sqlite in-memory db?

**Update**

When running `rake -t` It appears that rake is attempting to run the migrations

```
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:load
** Invoke db:test:load
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

I don't need to run migrations. Is it possible to override this seemingly default behavior.

Comment: This is a new think with rails 4. Ive never tried loading the schema but i would assume you are getting the exception before your schema loads, You may want to look at the setup hooks in your spec_helper configure block and put the schema loading stuff somewhere different, however it is more likely that boot.rb is throwing the exception :/

Comment: I don't believe this is rails 4 specific (but I could be wrong). It seems that rake is running `Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)`. I don't know why though.

Comment: Yeah, it runs that at every boot now since rails 4 im pretty sure. See https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/213839